# Inserting value to DB

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetnuke

I am new to DNN and .NEt in general so I probably made many mistakes here. My goal is to have a DNN module where you can upload an image with title and description - I did that by properly modifying the template module, using the item model/controller, etc. I tried to add an item rating model/controller, but I can't figure out where exactly I made the mistake.

My goal is for each item that was added to have an "Upvote" button, and that button would simply add an entry to the 2nd table I made in the database to count as an upvote. But with the current code, I can't get to a successful insert to db.

I'm working on an MVC module template and on DNN8 as a test environment.

Here is the project on my github (think it will be much easier): https://github.com/mheonyae/rating

The whole frontend can be seen in Index.cshtml:

```
<div id="Items-@Dnn.ModuleContext.ModuleId">
    @if (Model.Count() == 0)
    {
        <p>No meme's submited *SadPanda*</p>
    }
    else
    {
        <ul class="tm_tl">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <li class="tm_t">
                    <h3>@item.ItemName</h3>
                    <div class="upvote">



                        @Html.ActionLink(
                            "Upvote",                                                  // linkText
                            "UpvoteRating",                                    // actionName
                            "Item",                                                   // controllerName
                            new {                                                     // routeValues
                                item = item
                            },
                            null                                                      // htmlAttributes
                        )


                    </div>
                    <div class="tm_td">
                        <img src="~/desktopmodules/MVC/Memeometer/Memes/@item.ImagePath" style="float:left; width:220px; height:auto;" />

                    </div>
                    <div class="rating">
                        Rating:
                    </div>
                    @{
                        if (Dnn.ModuleContext.IsEditable)
                        {
                            <div>
                                <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Item", new {ctl = "Edit", itemId = item.ItemId})">@Dnn.LocalizeString("EditItem")</a>
                                <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Item", new {itemId = item.ItemId})">@Dnn.LocalizeString("DeleteItem")</a>
                            </div>
                        }
                    }
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    }
</div>
```

I am totally new to this so any in-depth explanation will be highly appreciated.

Comment: your repo project doesn't seem to compile by the way. one apparent thing it's missing is `web.config`

Comment: yeah i just excluded it when uploading because of my connection data, ill upload when i get to my home pc

Comment: I'd mock it up with DNN's default DB connection string

Comment: i've added web.config to repo

Answer (score 0):

Check out my DNN MVC module tutorial example that I use for training.  It has a fully working CRUD (Create/Read/Update/Delete) data repository and an image upload.

https://github.com/DotNetNuclear/DnnRestaurantMenu/tree/master/RestaurantMenu.MVC

You can download the source package and install the module to test.

https://github.com/DotNetNuclear/DnnRestaurantMenu/releases

Leave a comment with any further questions.

Comment: Thank you, i will have a look for sure. Actually i have a question right away, but i think my issue is more c#/.Net related than DNN itself. Im not quite sure if im doing the method calling the correct way, for my 2nd table/model or is there another mistake i made why my data is not being inserted.

Comment: It's hard to understand why something isn't inserted into the database.  You posted just the razor for your Index view.  When clicking your "Edit" action, I would expect it to go to an Edit controller action and display an edit razor view.  Like in my example, my Edit razor view has a "Submit" or save button. The Submit button will fire another controller action that performs the insert or update of the database record depending on whether we are editing an existing model (with an ID), or we started from an empty model with no ID.

Comment: I posted the link to my github repo, because i think it might be too much code to post here, and easier if i just share my whole module

Answer (score 0):

A couple of observations with your code that might be causing the issue:

For some reason in your `Index` razor view you opted to invoke `Item.UpvoteRating` and then call respective controller instead of calling `ItemRating.Upvote`, which I think makes more sense (this however is probably not an issue):

```cs
@Html.ActionLink(
   "Upvote",// linkText
   "Upvote",// actionName
   "ItemRating", // controllerName
   new {// routeValues
          id = item.ItemId // this will have to reflect your actual parameter
       },
   null  // htmlAttributes
)
```

Another thing (and I suspect this is the issue) is the properties on your `ItemRating` model (or lack thereof to be precise):

if you check out your database scripts (`DataProviders/.../00.00.01.SqlDataProvider`) you will see `ItemRatingId` as a PK for your `Memeometer_Item_Ratings` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE {databaseOwner}{objectQualifier}Memeometer_Item_Ratings
    (
    ItemRatingId int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    ItemIdFk int NOT NULL,
    PcIdentity nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
    ItemRatingPoints int NOT NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
     TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

while in your object you've got correct decorators, the class itself didn't have the property:

```cs
    [TableName("Memeometer_Item_Ratings")]
    [PrimaryKey("ItemRatingId", AutoIncrement = true)] // decoration looks good
    [Cacheable("ItemRatings", CacheItemPriority.Default, 20)]
    [Scope("ModuleId")]
    public class ItemRating
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; } = -1; // you have this, 
        public int ItemRatingId { get; set; } = -1; // while it likely needs to be this

        .......your other properties....
    }
```

hopefully that fixes the issue for you

Comment: Hello. That was definitelly a mistake on my part, but it still doesnt work. I assume the issue is in the way i call the controller action and try to deliver the data or the action itself.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint in your `ItemRating.Upvote()` method and see if that gets hit and what values get passed in? That will prove your theory